# Java: sorting students by their class level

Tags: java, sorting

I have a fairly large and mostly working program for my class. It's supposed to read the student and instructor files, and print them according to their courses. And that works properly. However, students have to be printed according to their class level, with seniors first and freshmen last. I checked some posts but I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```
public class Student extends Person
{
   String Course;
   int Credits;
   int Points;
   ArrayList<String> sortedStudentsList = new ArrayList<String>();

   public Student(String id, String first, String last)
   {
      super(id,first,last);
   }

   public void student(String enrolledStudents) throws Exception
   {
      String csvFile = "StudentData.csv";
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
      String line = null;
      String firstLine = br.readLine();

      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
      {
         String[] studentData = line.split(",");

         super.setID(studentData[0]);
         super.setFirstName(studentData[1]);
         super.setLastName(studentData[2]);
         setCredits(studentData[5]);
         setPoints(studentData[6]);
         setCourse(studentData[4]);

         ArrayList<String> studentArray = new ArrayList<String>();
         for(int k=0; k < 7; k--)
         {
            studentArray.add(studentData[k]);
         }

         Collections.sort(studentArray, sortStudentLevel);

         if(studentData[4].equals(enrolledStudents))
         {
            for (int i=0; i < studentArray.size(); i++)
            {
               System.out.println(super.getFirstName() + " " + super.getLastName() + ", ID Number " + super.getID() + ", is a " + studentData[3] + " enrolled in " + getCourse() + ". Earned " + getCredits() + " credit(s) and " + getPoints() + " point(s)");
            }  
         }
      }
    }

   public static Comparator<String> sortStudentLevel = new Comparator<String>()
   {
       int compare(String s1, String s2)
       {
          String classLevel1 = s1.getClassLevel();
          String classLevel2 = s2.getClassLevel();

          return classLevel1.compareTo(classLevel2);
       }
   };
}
```

I left out the setters and getters for this class, as I thought they are not that important. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: code formatting

Comment: `for(int k=0; k < 7; k--)`... Why `k--`? That is an infinite loop. And `k = -1` will throw an error

Comment: You should mention the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in the question.

Comment: What problem exactly are you facing? `Collections.sort(studentArray, sortStudentLevel);` at first glance looks OK so it seems that your problem is not related to title of this question. Please [edit] your post and properly describe what [doesn't work](http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/)

Comment: @Pshemo Comparator isn't correct. `s1.getClassLevel();`

Comment: @cricket_007 well, that is why I only said it "*looks* OK". OP claims that he removed some of getters so I am assuming that this may be one of them. Possible problems is that OP used String as description of level which could give some strange results when we will compare values like `"9"` with `"10"`. Anyway I am waiting for OP's *actual* problem description.

Comment: @Pshemo I meant. `String s1`, then `s1.getClassLevel()` won't compile.

Comment: @cricket_007 Brain fart... OK I need a break.

Comment: @cricket_007 *"That is an infinite loop."* No, it isn't, but the second part (will throw an ***exception***) was almost correct ;P.

Comment: @Tom Right. I edited once I saw the array access. Error/exception ... semantics ;P

Comment: @cricket_007 That loop also wouldn't be infinite if there were no exception in its body.

Comment: @Tom Why not? `k < 0` is always true, no? Int overflow?

Comment: @cricket_007 Not overflow, underflow. If it reached MIN_VALUE, it will then become MAX_VALUE and therefore `> 0` :P. But you're right that this is obviously not what OP wants :D.

Answer (score 2):

1) You want to sort a list of students. `s1.getClassLevel()` will not resolve for the `String s1`. You need a `Comparator<Student>`

2) To sort a List of `Student`, you need an `ArrayList<Student>` not an `ArrayList<String>();`

3) For every line of the CSV file, you made a brand new, empty `studentArray = new ArrayList<String>();`

4) You looped backwards over `studentData[k]` with `k--` in the loop

5) `enrolledStudents` does not appear to be defined. `if(studentData[4].equals(enrolledStudents))` doesn't really make sense in the context of the question. You just want to sort an print the list, right?

6) The `Student` class really shouldn't be responsible for reading a CSV file. It is a Model. It only holds the data, not perform any logic unrelated to a `Student`.

7) Maybe implement a `toString()` method on a Student.

```
@Override
public void toString() {
    return super.getFirstName() + " " + super.getLastName() + ", ID Number " + super.getID() + ", is a " + getClassLevel() + " enrolled in " + getCourse() + ". Earned " + getCredits() + " credit(s) and " + getPoints() + " point(s)";
}
```

8) Warning on comparing Strings for the class level. I believe `"10".compareTo("9") < 0` evaluates to `true` and `"sophomore".compareTo("senior") < 0` evaluates to `false`, for example.

---

All in all, this should be in the `main` method, or somewhere other than the `Student` class.

```
String csvFile = "StudentData.csv";
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
String line = null;
String firstLine = br.readLine(); // skip header

ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
     String[] studentData = line.split(",");
     Student s = new Student(studentData[0], studentData[1], studentData[2]);

     s.setClassLevel(studentData[3]); // You need this if you want to sort by it
     s.setCourse(studentData[4]);
     s.setCredits(studentData[5]);
     s.setPoints(studentData[6]);


     students.add(s); // Add one row of CSV to list
} // Done reading the file. 

// Now, sort list
Collections.sort(studentArray, new Comparator<Student>() {
   int compare(Student s1, Student s2)
   {
      String classLevel1 = s1.getClassLevel();
      String classLevel2 = s2.getClassLevel();

      return classLevel1.compareTo(classLevel2);
   }
}); // Done sorting

// Now print the students
for (Student s : students) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```